# Merge Object & Array: Javascript, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, extend

**Illustrative example:**

```
d1 = {
  "ean_code": ["OA13233394CN08", "8903327046534", "8903327014779"],
  "balance_qty": [5, 10, 15]
}
```

And

```
d2 = {
  "ean_code": ["OA13233394CN11", "OA13233394CN08", "8903327014779", "OA13233394CN09"],
  "scanned_qty": [30, 5, 20, 10, - 1],
}
```

Output:

```
d3 = {
  "ean_code": ["OA13233394CN08", "8903327046534", "8903327014779", "OA13233394CN11", "OA13233394CN09"],
  "scanned_qty": [5, 0, 20, 30, 10],
  "balance_qty": [5, 10, 15, 0, 0]
}
```

**Explaination**. `d3['scanned_qty'][1]` default value is `0`, because value of `d3['ean_code'][1]` is belongs to `d1['ean_code']` array and `d1` object doesn't have `scanned_qty` key.

Best possible way to do this operation?

Comment: "All arrays should have the same length" is a completely different task, isn't it? Would cutting them be OK? If not, why fill with empty strings (especially as some arrays consist of numbers only)?

Comment: @Bergi: To resolve index problem am keeping them empty string, Ex. in d1['a'] & d2['a'] creating d3['a'] having array length 4. & now d1 doesn't have 'c' key & d2 has 'c' key which is mapping with d2['a'] but 10 of d1['a'], d1 doesn't have 'c' key thats why keeping d3['c'][3] as empty string.

Comment: Index problem? Sounds like you want to solve it in the wrong place. Why don't you adapt the loop instead of creating empty strings?

Comment: @Bergi: Please have look at my actual object with few keys.
let me know if you still have confusion.

Comment: @Niks Did my edited answer not do what you were looking for? Are you not looking for equal-length fields anymore? I'm confused. I feel like your question now is very different from the original one you posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a custom solution for your specific case.

- Merge 2 objects with no sub-objects (no recursion required)
- Final object's array fields must be the same length
- Final object's array fields must preserve index coherency
- Final object's array fields must use '0' as a default value

---

http://jsfiddle.net/8X5yB/4/

```
function customMerge(a, b, uniqueKey) {
    var result = {};
    var temp = {};
    var fields = {};
    // object 1
    for(var x=0; x<a[uniqueKey].length; x++) {
        id = a[uniqueKey][x];
        if(temp[id] == null) temp[id] = {};
        for(k in a) {
            if(k != uniqueKey) {
                fields[k] = '';
                temp[id][k] = (a[k].length > x ? a[k][x] : 0);
            }
        }
    }
    // object 2
    for(var x=0; x<b[uniqueKey].length; x++) {
        id = b[uniqueKey][x];
        if(temp[id] == null) temp[id] = {};
        for(k in b) {
            if(k != uniqueKey) {
                fields[k] = '';
                temp[id][k] = (b[k].length > x ? b[k][x] : 0);
            }
        }
    }
    // create result
    result[uniqueKey] = [];
    for(f in fields) result[f] = [];
    for(k in temp) {
        result[uniqueKey].push(k);
        for(f in fields) {
            result[f].push(temp[k][f] != null ? temp[k][f] : 0);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
...
var obj = customMerge(d1, d2, "ean_code");
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have o1 and o2 as object 1 and 2, respectively.

```
var key,
    result = {}
    i,
    largestLength = 0,
    copyIntoResult = function (obj, key) {
        for (i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i += 1) {
            if (result[key].indexOf(obj[key][i]) === -1) {
                result[key].push(obj[key][i]);
            }
        }
    };

for (key in o1) {
    if (o1.hasOwnProperty(key) && o2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result[key] = [];
        copyIntoResult(o1, key);
        copyIntoResult(o2, key);
        if (result[key].length > largestLength) {
            largestLength = result[key].length;
        }
    } else if (o1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        result[key] = [].concat(o1[key]);
        if (o1[key].length > largestLength) {
            largestLength = o1[key].length;
        }
    }
}
for (key in o2) {
    if (o2.hasOwnProperty(key) && !result[key]) {
        result[key] = [].concat(o2[key]);
        if (o2[key].length > largestLength) {
            largestLength = o2[key].length;
        }
    }
}

// result now has the merged result

for (key in result) {
    if (result[key].length < largestLength) {
        for (i = 0; i < (largestLength - result[key].length); i += 1) {
            result[key].push('');
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Upon the edit to your question, you can have all the arrays be the same length by equalizing the arrays to the maximum array length of the merged result. However, the default "blank" entry is up to you (in this case, I just used an empty string).

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but .concat won't "merge", it will but all the values from one array next to the values from the other.

Comment: @Vinay: its working fine, But i want unique merging values in each array

Comment: @Niks use Vinary 's code but replace the .concat() parts with Underscore's union funcion: http://underscorejs.org/#union

Comment: No I have posted new code that should merge only unique values (no duplicates). No need for underscore.

Comment: @Vinay: Its working awsm but need one more help, please have look at edited question.

Answer (score 0):

```
function merge(a,b) {
    var c = {};
    for(key in a.keys()) {
        c[key] = a[key].slice(0);
    }
    for(key in b.keys()) {
        if(typeof c[key] == 'undefined') {
            c[key] = b[key].slice(0);
        } else {
            var adds = b[key].filter(function(item){ 
                return (a[key].indexOf(item) == -1);
            });
            c[key].concat(adds);
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

- [.keys() method since v1.8.5, snippet for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).
- [filter since v1.6, snippet for older browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [concat since v1.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).